# Ghdl format file not recognized

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

After elaborating with ghdl I get the following error:

```
e~hello_world.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
C:\Users\Public\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe: compilation error
```

Mind that I'm trying to run the simple hello_world program that is in the docs of ghdl.
I'm running on Windows with llvm as a backend and the version of ghdl is:

```
GHDL 0.37 (v0.37) [Dunoon edition]
Compiled with GNAT Version: 9.1.0
 llvm code generator
Written by Tristan Gingold.
```

Comment: I'm not a Windows user and can't advise a fix. See [How to run ghdl-0.34-dev-mingw64-llvm without MinGW64? #318](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/issues/318). Your either missing gcc, have the wrong gcc or the installation is damaged or can't be found.  ghdl requires gcc to call ld which also apparently involves collect2. gcc isn't included with the [ghdl-0.37-mingw64-llvm.zip](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/releases/download/v0.37/ghdl-0.37-mingw64-llvm.zip) release found [here](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/releases/tag/v0.37).

Comment: Please show us your command lines you use.

Comment: One thing to check is that you don't have different tools versions (like "ld" from a different gcc or llvm version) from those installed as part of ghdl. You might try "which ghdl" and "which collect2" and if they have different paths, you may need to sort that out. (I don't know how the LLVM backend affects this, sorry)

Answer (score -1):

It turns out the problem was with the gcc, I uninstalled and installed a new version

Comment: The problem gcc was a 32 bit?

Comment: could you elaborate on which version of gcc was the wrong version, and which version was the right version?